# How to find all symbols between characters

Tags: regex

I need to get all `-` characters between `###`.

Input string: `### qwerty-qwerty-qwerty-qwerty - - - ###`

```
(?<=###)\s?([\-]*)\s?(?=###)
```

Thanks in advance.

http://regex101.com/r/jL9lZ9/1

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I need to replace all `-` to empty string.

Comment: Which language did you use?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I'm just wondering how to do it :) It's not real problem. You can do it on regex101. Thanks.

Comment: What should be replaced in `### -a- ### -b- ###`?

Comment: What about this http://regex101.com/r/jL9lZ9/3 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, nice! You can convert your comment to answer. I accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match `-` symbols which are present within `###`,

```
(?:^(?:(?!###).)*(?=###.*?###)|(?<=###)(?:(?!###).)*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|-
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL9lZ9/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
  (?!.*?###.*?###.*?)(?=.*?###)-
```

This works as well.
See Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/jL9lZ9/4

Answer (score 0):

This ones a 2 step one, slightly different but more understandable. Can use this if we are try to extract a pattern(`-`) between a specific pattern(`###`).

```
text="- qwe--### -- - qwerty- --## -qwerty --- ###- qwerty-- qw- - ### - rty--"
```

Note that there is a double hash(`##`) here, now assuming that we want `-`s between triple hashes(`###`) only

use this to extract required text `(?<=###)[^#]*(?=###)`

After that its just this `-` to extract

you can replace the boundary patterns and search patterns as required.